# multiple instances of rocksdb

Tags: rocksdb

On a multi-core server (or cluster) want to deploy a rocksdb db on each core that is independent of each other ie. *not* looking for a distributed db. Is this possible?

For each in-memory db, does it need to communicate with storage during runtime operations ie. *not* at startup or close down or are all db operations performed in-memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes, it's possible.  RocksDB is simply a C++ library which you can compile with your code that manages multiple rocksdb instances a multi-core server (or cluster).  Multiple rocksdb instances can also share the same set of resources (such as sharing the same thread pool) by having them using the same Env (see [Options::env](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/include/rocksdb/options.h#L578)).

```
// Use the specified object to interact with the environment,
// e.g. to read/write files, schedule background work, etc.
// Default: Env::Default()
Env* env;
```

2) if the directory of your rocksdb instance is in memory (such as mounting via [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs)), then all db operations are guaranteed to be performed in-memory. To make such rocksdb persistent, you can also optionally have write-ahead-log writing to some persistent storage like flash or disk.